# Creating a reusable "base" class extending javax.ws.rs.core.Application

Tags: java, web-services, inheritance, design-patterns, jax-rs

The following is a question being implemented with Java EE 6 using the Java 7 JDK.

### Situation

I'm trying to implement a solution where I have a sort of "core" or "base" version of a [`javax.ws.rs.core.Application`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Application.html) class.  I have a core framework that is a separate Java Project which at this point exists as a *core.jar* that other applications can include.  What I want to do is have something like a "CoreApplication" in this core framework that extends the jax-rs `Application` class, which would look something like this:

```
@ApplicationPath("")
public class CoreApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {

        Set<Class<?>> resources = new HashSet<Class<?>>();

        resources.add(ApiListingResource.class);
        resources.add(SwaggerSerializers.class);
        // Other common resources from the core framework

        return resources;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Object> getSingletons() {

        Set<Object> singletons = new HashSet<Object>();

        // Register the Jackson provider for JSON
        JacksonJaxbJsonProvider jaxbProvider = new JacksonJaxbJsonProvider();
        jaxbProvider.setMapper(getUniversalJacksonMapper());

        singletons.add(jaxbProvider);
        // Other common singletons from the core framework

        return singletons;
    } 
}
```

### Problem

If I include my *core.jar* in an application that it is using and try to do something like this:

```
public class ChildApplication extends CoreApplication {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {

        Set<Class<?>> resources = super.getClasses();

        resources.add(ChildSpecificResource.class);

        return resources;
    }

    ...
```

}

then this `ChildApplication` class is never run.  What happens instead is that the `CoreApplication` class is run (assumedly because it *actually* extends the jax-rs `Application` class) and the `ChildApplication` is disregarded.

What I seem to need to do is make sure the `ChildApplication` class directly extends `Application` - that is apparently the only way it will be invoked. So if I do that then I need a way to inherit the `CoreApplication` class in my child applications.  I thought of a couple of ways to try to solve this problem but neither work.

1. Keep `CoreApplication` as a class and inherit both `CoreApplication` and `Application` from `ChildApplication`.  This blatantly won't work because Java doesn't allow multiple inheritance.
2. Make `CoreApplication` an interface.  This would work in some regards but then I can only inherit the method signatures in `ChildApplication` which doesn't give me the real code reuse I'm after.

I was wondering if anyone could suggest the best design to solve this problem.

Thanks to all who help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both classes actually extend `Application`, so that is not the problem. The problem is the `@ApplicationPath` annotation. The class with this annotation is used asthe main configuration class.

Comment: Nice!  That worked perfectly which means the design I had originally was possible.  I didn't realize the annotation controlled the main configuration.  I also tried to keep the annotation on the `CoreApplication` class as well as add it to the `ChildApplication` class which also worked.  I'm not sure if that is advisable or not, but apparently it is possible to have the `@ApplicationPath` on both the parent and child.  Thanks again.